# Установка WebLogic

Tags: java, jar, weblogic

Пытаюсь установить сервер WebLogic

1. Поместил файл fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls_quick.jar в C:\Windows\System32
2. В переменных окружения прописан путь к java.exe (JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin") - в этой папке есть java.exe
3. Запускаю: java -jar fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls_quick.jar от имени администратора

Вывод:

C:\Windows\system32>java -jar fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls_quick.jar
Launcher log file is C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall201
9-08-28_10-06-01AM\launcher2019-08-28_10-06-01AM.log.
Extracting the installer . . . . . . . . . . . . . Done
**This installer must be executed using a Java Development Kit (JDK)
but C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221 is not a valid JDK Java Home.**
The log is located here: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstal
l2019-08-28_10-06-01AM\launcher2019-08-28_10-06-01AM.log.

Почему не валидный JDK Java Home?

Comment: Вы знаете что такое JRE, или как вы поняли сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: JRE - окружение, JDK - инструментарий, понял так что он не может найти JDK, видимо, java.exe. Но здесь не может быть причина в пробелах в пути (Program Files)? Это Win 64

Comment: JAVA_HOME -> путь до jdk нужен, а не до jre. Пример: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221"

Comment: @АнатолийЭрнст ^^^

Comment: А.. понял, спасибо